# Excel copy range and paste in a specific range available and print

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to copy a range in one sheet and paste it as a value in another sheet, but just in a specific range in the next available cell in column B. Starting from B4 to B23 only.

I changed some code I found online but it's not working for me in finding the next available row. After I run the macro the first time, when I run it again and again it does nothing, and it's not working in pasting only the values either.

I tried saving the file before running the Macro again, but still it's not working.

At the end, when the range in the Print sheet is full, I would like a message box asking me to select one of the printers (not the default) on one of my servers (specifying the server path in the code like \a_server_name) and print this Print Sheet only, or clear the records in the range in the Print Sheet, or save only the Sheet Print in a new file (SaveAs) to a location I can choose on one of my servers (specifying the server path in the code \a_server_name) or simply do nothing and end the sub.

Thank you.

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim copySheet As Worksheet
Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet

Set copySheet = Worksheets(“Data”)
Set pasteSheet = Worksheets("Print”)

copySheet.Range("J11:Q11").Copy
pasteSheet.Range("B4:I23").End(xlUp).Offset(1,0)
.PasteSpecial.xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

[image]

[image]

[image: Problem Screenshot]

Comment: You are using the wrong quotes. Remove all smart quotes and replace with `"`

Comment: Will the copy range always be `J11:Q11`?

Comment: Yes, Urdearboy, the copy range is always J11:Q11 in the Data Sheet

Comment: What is your definition of a *full range*?

Comment: In this case I would like my paste range to be limited to "B4:I23" only.

Comment: I did but it still pasted below my range. I checked all the formatting for the cells below the range, there are more merged cells/rows, but I don't think it matters. :( It basically pastes the J11:Q11 at the very bottom, below everything.

Comment: I was thinking of changing the B4:I23 in the Print Sheet into a table but then I got lost... anyways I don't even think it may work. ;( thank you for all your help though

Comment: what if we put a "IF" condition before my code? Something like:                     
Dim testEmpty As String 
testEmpty = ""
If(IsEmpty(testEmpty) = true) Then                                                                           Adding a LastRow = 23                                                                                
Or something similar...do you think it will work? Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what i can gather, you want to copy 8 cells and paste all 8 cells to 20 rows, starting at B4. You are not clear on how you want to rerun the macro, it will just write over the data you just pasted.

The first code will copy the 8 cells into the 20 rows

```
With ThisWorkbook
        Sheets("Data").Range("J11:Q11").Copy
        Sheets("Print").Range("B4:I23").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
End With
```

This second code uses a for loop to accoplish the same task, but it also will write over the previously pasted data.

```
Dim i As Long
    With ThisWorkbook
        For i = 4 To 23
            Sheets("Data").Range("J11:Q11").Copy
            Sheets("Print").Cells(i, 2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Next i
    End With
```

If you want to be able to reuse the macro, you will have to modify the range to be copied that allows you to select the range you want to copy. Maybe a variable that allows a user input with a `InputBox`.

Edit:

```
Dim lRow As Long
lRow = Sheets("Print").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

    With ThisWorkbook
            Sheets("Data").Range("J11:Q11").Copy
            Sheets("Print").Cells(lRow, 2).Offset(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    End With
```

Edit #3

```
With ThisWorkbook
    Dim lRow As Long
    lRow = .Sheets("Print").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Sheets("Data").Range("J11:Q11").Copy
        Sheets("Print").Cells(lRow, 2).Offset(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
End With
```

Comment: The second code is good GMalc, but it copies the same data in all the rows, I just need it to copy the J11:Q11 once, then, when I change the data in J11:Q11, I would like to run the code again and paste the new data in the next available row, which will be B5:I5, and then, after that, I will change the data in J11:Q11 again and the code must recognize the next available row to paste it, which will be B6:I6 and so on... till B23:I23.

Comment: @MyExcelJoe Ah!!! Clarity is good, when you ask a question you need to be specific on what you want. Any answer that someone provides is based on what you give.  Is B3 the last cell with data in it?

Comment: It doesn't work. Same problem I had before B4 (it pastes the results after the range). Maybe because of the formatting of the merged cells before. Please see my pictures posted. Consider that B2 and B3 have been merged (vertical like the others in the rows 2 and 3), while B1 has been merged though P1 (Horiz). Maybe that's why is not working, but I am not sure.

Comment: I tried the last code with no merged cell, but nothing, maybe other formatting. The 2nd code was kind of working, but repeating the same data across the whole range. Please see my second picture.

Comment: @MyExcelJoe We're getting more clarity, good, i will get back to you.

Comment: @MyExcelJoe Try the third edit it should do what you want it to.

Comment: It works in moving to the next line when I re-run the macro, but I don't know why it starts pasting after the whole range...  :( Your second code was able to start pasting exactly from B4:I4... but then it was keep repeating the loop until B23:I23, instead of stopping at B5:I5.

Comment: @MyExcelJoe being clear is very important, you need to explain what you mean by "starts pasting after the whole range"? This is what i think you are saying... You want to copy a range of 8 specific cells and then paste to the first empty cell in column B, then after those 8 cell are manually changed, you want to run the macro and paste to the next row below the previous paste. If you are trying to copy different ranges and then paste them, you need to be more specific in your details of what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @MyExcelJoe My day is done, i will try to get to this tomorrow

Comment: No, GMalc you're correct. The problem is that with your last code the macro pastes the selection in Cell B24 instead of B4. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I have uploaded a picture to explain the problem, please let me know if you need more info. Thank you

Comment: You need to clear those cells. On `Sheet("Print")`, select Cells(A4:A23). In the `Home Tab`, in the `Editing Section`, select `Clear` and `Clear All`. Then with the range selected `Right Click` on the range and select `Delete` `shift left`. Close and save the workbook. Restart and Run the macro again.

Answer (score 1):

This will set the values equal to each other without copying/pasting.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Testing()

Dim wsC As Worksheet: Set wsC = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
Dim wsP As Worksheet: Set wsP = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Print")

Dim LRow As Long
LRow = wsP.Range("B" & wsP.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

wsP.Range("B" & LRow).Resize(wsC.Range("J11:Q11").Rows.Count, wsC.Range("J11:Q11").Columns.Count).Value = wsC.Range("J11:Q11").Value

End Sub
```

---

Modifying your code - and reducing to minimal example

```
Sub test()

Dim copySheet As Worksheet: Set copySheet = Worksheets("Data")
Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet: Set pasteSheet = Worksheets("Print")

copySheet.Range("J11:Q11").Copy
pasteSheet.Range("B" & pasteSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

End Sub
```

Comment: Nope, Unfortunately it doesn't work. It pasted the J11:Q11 content below all my established range in the other Print Sheet. The code I posted was working fine in finding the first row in the "B4:I4" range on the Print Sheet, just it does not work when running the code again in finding B5:I5 and so on.

Comment: I added a second option that resembles the code you shared. Both of these work fine on my end

Comment: It still doesn't work. It paste the results all at the bottom of my range. Please, Urdearboy check the picture I posted. I think it doesn't work because of the cell formatting (Merge and so on). However, my original code it works in finding the first B4:I4 even with this formatting.